# Calculate the probability of the first bulb to be burnt before the second one

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand and then generalize an exercise I saw. There were two lightbulbs. One has lifetime $X\sim \exp(1)$ months and second one has lifetime $Y\sim \exp(3)$ months. We turn on the first lightbulb and after one month we turn the second one (even if the first one is burnt until then). We want to calculate the probability of the first bulb to be burnt before the second one. It means we need to calculate $P(X<Y+1)$. What they did:
$$
\begin{align*}
P\left(X<Y+1\right)&=P\left(X<Y+1|X<1\right)\cdot P\left(X<1\right)+P\left(X<Y+1|X>1\right)\cdot P\left(X>1\right)\\&=(1-e^{-1})+\frac{1}{3+1}e^{-1}=0.724
\end{align*}
$$
First of all I don't understand how did they got the answer. I do understand that:
$$
P\left(X<1\right)=1-P\left(X\geq1\right)=1-e^{-1\cdot1}=1-e^{-1}\\P\left(X>1\right)=e^{-1\cdot1}=e^{-1}
$$
But this means that they think that $P\left(X<Y+1|X<1\right)=1$. Why? Also I see that $P\left(X<Y+1|X>1\right)=\frac{1}{3+1}$. So i'm guessing that they want me to say: $P\left(X<Y+1|X>1\right)=P\left(X<Y\right)$ (because then I understand why it's $\frac{1}{3+1}$). I also guess it has to do something with memorylessness. But I have never saw memorylessness which uses the two (or more) random variables. I'm familiar with $P(X>s+t|X>s)=P(X>t)$. But here we have another random variable $Y$.

To sum up, I have the following questions:

1. What is the memorylessness formula for two random variables? I think it will help me to understand second question.
2. Why $P\left(X<Y+1|X<1\right)=1$ and why $P\left(X<Y+1|X>1\right)=P\left(X<Y\right)$.
3. Given $X\sim\exp(\lambda_X)$ and $Y\sim\exp(\lambda_Y)$. Can we evaluate $P(X<Y+a)$ where $a\geq0$?

Comment: What are the time units of  the lifetime?

Comment: @user months (I'll add it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this means that they think that $\Pr[X < Y+1 \mid X < 1] = 1$. Why?

Because we require that $Y$ has a nonnegative lifetime, i.e. $Y \ge 0$; thus $Y + 1 \ge 1$, and given $X < 1$, we must have $X < Y + 1$ with certainty.

> I also guess it has to do something with memorylessness.

That is correct.  Once the first bulb has lasted $1$ month, i.e. $X > 1$, its future lifetime is still exponential with mean $1$ month, due to memorylessness.  In other words, each moment that a bulb is still working, its future lifetime from that point forward is still exponential with the same parameter--as if it were a *new* bulb that had just been turned on.  So the conditional probability is simply $$\Pr[X < Y + 1 \mid X > 1] = \Pr[X < Y].$$  This has less to do with whether we have two random variables in the conditional probability than it has to do with what the notation actually is saying about what is happening with the bulbs.  If the first bulb has survived one month, it is as if it is new, so now the situation is equivalent to comparing the lifetimes of the two bulbs as if they had been turned on simultaneously, and seeing if the first one dies before the second.

I should point out that the solution you have provided implies that on average, the lifetime of the second bulb is shorter than the lifetime of the first; i.e., the notation $Y \sim \operatorname{Exp}(3)$ means $Y$ has *mean* lifetime $1/3$ months, not $3$ months, and $3$ is a rate parameter, not a scale parameter.

It is not difficult to extend the above to the general case described in your third question.  You want $$\begin{align}
\Pr[X < Y + a] &= \Pr[X < Y + a \mid X \le a]\Pr[X \le a] + \Pr[X < Y + a \mid X > a]\Pr[X > a] \\
&= 1(1 - e^{-\lambda_x a}) + \frac{\lambda_x}{\lambda_x + \lambda_y}(e^{-\lambda_x a}). \end{align}$$  A computational proof, however, is more involved:  one would need to evaluate $$
\Pr[X < Y + a] = \int_{y=0}^\infty \Pr[X \le y+a]f_Y(y) \, dy = \int_{y=0}^\infty (1 - e^{-\lambda_x(y+a)})\lambda_y e^{-\lambda_y y} \, dy.$$  One obtains the same result in both cases.