# Given that the first lightbulb is turned for more than one month, what's the expected value until one of the two lightbulbs is burnt?

Tags: probability

Following my previous question [Calculate the probability of the first bulb to be burnt before the second one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017517/calculate-the-probability-of-the-first-bulb-to-be-burnt-before-the-second-one/4017537#4017537), which I'll add here so you won't have to jump back there:

> There were two lightbulbs. One has lifetime $X\sim \exp(1)$ months and second one has lifetime $Y\sim \exp(3)$ months. We turn on the first lightbulb and after one month we turn the second one (even if the first one is burnt until then).

Given that the first lightbulb is turned for more than one month, what's the expected value of the time from turning the first lightbulb until one of the two lightbulbs is burnt?

As I understand, we want to calculate $E\left(\min\left\{X,Y\right\} |X>1\right)$. We know that $\min\left\{ T_{A},T_{B}\right\} \sim\exp\left(4\right)$. But now I'm stuck. In the solution they did:
$$
E\left(\min\left\{X,Y\right\} |X>1\right)=1+\frac{1}{4}=1.25
$$
Is it possible to explain how did they got to $1+\frac{1}{4}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1- Intuitive explanation**

Given that $X>1$, using memoryless property you can say that at the time 1 the bulbs are "good as new", thus the mean is $1+E(U)=1+\frac{1}{4}$

**2- Analytic solution**

Given that $X>1$ also $U=\min(X,Y)>1$ thus

$$f_{U|U>1}(u)=e^44e^{-4u}\mathbb{1}_{[1;+\infty)}(u)$$

Using the definition, the expectation is

$$e^4\int_1^{+\infty}4ue^{-4u}du=\frac{5}{4}$$

Comment: Is it true to say that if $X\sim \exp(\lambda_X)$ and $Y\sim\exp(\lambda_Y)$ then $E(\min\{X,Y\}|X>a)=a+E(\min\{X,Y\})$? Is it true for other distributions?

Comment: @abuka123 : this is exactly what I wrote in 1-. No, in general is it not true. It is true in all the distribution with memoryless property